# PUN2 not connecting after loadScene

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I have a strange issue, which I ran into about a year ago which made me give up. Now, I want to tackle this, but can't for the life of me find the reason for this problem.

The setting:

- Game with PUN v2 configured;
- PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings(); gets called when clicking 'Multiplayer' button;

Working repro:

- Start the game;
- Menu scene gets loaded via Unity SceneManager.LoadScene;
- Click 'Multiplayer' button;
- PUN2 connects as expected.

The issue repro:

- Start the game;
- Menu scene gets loaded via Unity SceneManager.LoadScene;
- I start a different scene, e.g. singleplayer;
- Singleplayer scene gets loaded via Unity SceneManager.LoadScene;
- I quit the singleplayer, and go back to Menu;
- Menu scene gets loaded via Unity SceneManager.LoadScene;
- Click 'Multiplayer' button;
- PUN2 doesn't connect at all.
- I have to restart the game in the Unity editor to actually get it to connect as per the 'working' repro; The 'issue' repro is consistent in that it never allows connection when I load a different scene in between.

I don't use anything fancy or complex, just very straight-forward setup.

The logging:

### Working Repro (after start, clicking 'Multiplayer' to call PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSetttings):
SocketUdpAsync, .Net, Unity.

### IPhotonSocket.Connect() ns.exitgames.com:5058 this.Protocol: Udp

### ns.exitgames.com resolved to 1 address(es): 172.65.231.130 (InterNetwork(2))

### queueIncomingCommand() CMD(6 ch#/sq#/usq#: 0/1/0 r#/st/tt:0/0/0) channel seq# r/u: 0/0

### Connected to nameserver.

### Issue Repro (after start, open a different scene, load back menu scene, clicking 'Multiplayer' to call PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSetttings):
SocketUdpAsync, .Net, Unity.

### IPhotonSocket.Connect() ns.exitgames.com:5058 this.Protocol: Udp

That's it. Here it hangs indefinitely.

Why does this happen?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all start by applying better formatting to your question's text. Secondly, the setup you have provided in order to make your question reproducible is not reproducible since working with PUN requires another setup in photon dashboard. Have you properly connected your Photon's appID? Are you behind a firewall which may be blocking Unity's traffic? Are you living in an area which may be affected by IP bans? try running your example one more time with an active VPN connection.

Comment: Hi, I can connect without issue. There is no firewall, IP bans or other network impacting issues. All is set up correctly, and it works, until I load a different scene.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:
TimeScale was set to 0. PUN requires a TimeScale of > 0 to work.

Comment: You should accept this reply as the answer to your question.